# Moving a VM from MS Virtual Server R2 to VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, migration, vhd, virtual-server-2005-r2

I have a Windows 2000 Professional VM happily running under MS Virtual Server R2 on WindowsXP.  I need to move it to a different PC and the only one available is a Mac with VirtualBox on it.

Theoretically, VirtualBox accepts .VHD files out of the box, but my attempts to run my VHD on VirtualBox resulted in failure.  The Guest OS just keeps rebooting.

I've attempted to get help on the VirtualBox forums, and they said that the VM image must first be prepped for the move, but could not give me any specifics.

Anyone here know what is specifically involved in moving a Win2k .VHD to VirtualBox on the Mac?

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem with the image, but with drivers and/or registry entries for devices. Try to find a way to stop constant rebooting. In XP, enter in safe mode and hit F8 few times, then you can see the problem like

> STOP: 0x0000007B (0xF741B84C,0xC0000034,0x00000000,0x00000000) INACCESSIBLE_BOOT_DEVICE

Find the exact problem and fix it on the source VM, like changing registry entries or adding drivers. Then move that image to virtualbox.